# Deleting all selected rows using easyui and php

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-easyui

I have created the following function to get all my selection and send the selected ids to another php file (process.php) for processing.

Here is my function:

```
function getSelections(){
            var ss = [];
            var rows = $('#dga').datagrid('getSelections');
            if (rows){
            $.messager.confirm('Confirm','Are you sure you want to delete this user?',function(r){
                    if (r){
                        for(var i=0; i<rows.length; i++){
                            var row = rows[i];
                            ss.push(row.id);
                            }
                        /*$.messager.alert('Info', ss.join('<br/>')); for testing*/
                    $.post('process.php', ss.join({id:row.id}),function(result){
                    if (result.success){
                        $('#dga').datagrid('reload');   // reload the user data
                    } else {
                        $.messager.show({   // show error message
                            title: 'Error',
                            msg: result.msg
                        });
                    }
                },'json');
            }
        });
    } 
}
```

I want to get the data by this medthod in `process.php`:

```
$id = intval($_REQUEST['id']);
include 'conn.php';
$N = count($id);
for($i=0; $i < $N; $i++){
$sql = "delete from user where id=$id[$i]";
$result = @mysql_query($sql);
    if ($result){
        echo json_encode(array('success'=>true));
        } else {
        echo json_encode(array('msg'=>'There is error.'));
        }
}
```

I could not delete multiple rows. I could only delete single user at a time. Please help me. 
What I want to achieve:
I want to delete all my selections (all users selected using checkbox) in one go and reload the grid? The answer below works with single record but not works with multiple records. Any help and suggestion are greatly appreciated. It is a part of my project.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
function getSelections() {
    var rows = $('#dga').datagrid('getSelections');
    if (rows) {
        $.messager.confirm('Confirm', 'Are you sure you want to delete this user?', function (r) {
            if (r) {
                var ss = $.map(rows, function (item, idx) {
                    return item.id;
                });
                /*$.messager.alert('Info', ss.join('<br/>')); for testing*/
                $.post('process.php', {
                    'id[]': ss
                }, function (result) {
                    aler(result.success)
                    if (result.success) {
                        $('#dga').datagrid('reload'); // reload the user data
                    } else {
                        $.messager.show({ // show error message
                            title: 'Error',
                            msg: result.msg
                        });
                    }
                }, 'json').fail(function (jxhr, status, error) {
                    alert('error: ' + status + ':' + error)
                });
            }
        });
    }
}
```

then

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
include 'conn.php';
$N = count($id);
for($i=0; $i < $N; $i++){
$sql = "delete from user where id=$id[$i]";
$result = @mysql_query($sql);
    if ($result){
        echo json_encode(array('success'=>true));
        } else {
        echo json_encode(array('msg'=>'There is error.'));
        }
}
```

Comment: `There is error` this is what I get. In the console, it looks fine. It does not reload the grid as well.

Comment: why is the reload not working? Please can you suggest the alternative way. Your answer did delete the records without `intval()` but the reload is working for just one record deletion and not working multiple records deletion.

Comment: @ImaSinate whether the error message is shown if multiple records are deleted

Comment: if intval() is used, the error is shown. Reload only works if a single row is deleted. With multiple records, the reload does not work.

Comment: @ImaSinate whether the records are getting deleted if multiple recoreds are selected

Comment: @ImaSinate add `alert(result.success)` before `if (result.success) {`

Comment: there is no popup alert even after adding `alert(result.success)`.

Comment: @ImaSinate see the updated answer.. the `.fail()` part

Comment: TypeError: $.post(...).fail is not a function
}, 'json').fail(function (jxhr, status, error) {
this is the console error.

Comment: @ImaSinate jquery version used? change `fail` to `error`

Comment: Version 1.4.4.min it is bundled with easyui 1.3.6

Comment: then the `fail` won't work, you need to use `.error`

Comment: With single record everything is fine. But with multiple records. The reload does not work.

Answer (score -1):

You could delete multiple rows using a statement like

```
DELETE FROM user WHERE id IN (1,2,3,4)
```

Click [here](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/sql-in.aspx) for full explanation. Let me know if this helps!

Comment: It's not in the query, it is in the jquery function that I could not figure out.

Comment: Can you share the URL of the page where this JS funciton is used?

Comment: I am following the easyui example here at http://www.jeasyui.com/tutorial/datagrid/datagrid3.php

Comment: Ok, now I see the problem. You need to have { id: ss} instead of ss.join({id:row.id})

Comment: Yes, it works. but the reload is not working. What could be the problem?

Comment: What do you mean by reload?